# Why is "binoculars" used in the plural form?

Tags: word-usage

I don't quite understand because it already has "two" in itself as "bi", making the word mean "two eyes".

Then "a pair of binoculars" has four eyes, doesn't it?

Why wouldn't it be used in the singular form just like "bicycle"?

"Bicycle" consists of two wheels, and it isn't "a pair of cycles" or "a pair of bicycles" but just a bicycle.

Answer (score 4):

'Binoculars' is plural because it is an abbreviation for *a pair of binoculars*.

Similar, *a monocle* enhances one eye, whereas *a pair of spectacles* is for two eyes.

The term 'binocular is also an adjective meaning "related to two eyes" (just as 'monocular' means related to one eye). A telescope gives you monocular vision, whereas a pair of binoculars give you binocular vision (3-dimensional). You could technically achieve binocular vision by using two telescopes, so you can appreciate why having a piece of equipment that incorporates both lenses is *a pair*.

Some other items are also considered to be 'pairs', hence plural, despite being one piece of equipment, for example, *a pair of scissors*, or *a pair of compasses*.

Your point about bicycles doesn't really follow. Sure, it has two wheels, but it only has one cycling mechanism. It is a piece of equipment that cycles, or turns, two wheels. It's not called a 'biwheel' (although, another name for a unicycle is a 'monowheel').

Comment: "Pair of pants" is the example that sprang to my mind, of something constructed as a plural but used as a singular.

Comment: The real mystery is how it became plural in the first place. [Etymonline](https://www.etymonline.com/word/binoculars) simply says that it came from *binocular*, which it shows in 1871 was "short for *binocular glass*". Why we took an adjective and morphed it into a plural noun is unclear to me, unless it's simply the power of suggestion in the "bi-" (in which case, the OP might reasonably wonder why *bicycle* didn't evolve the same way).

Comment: It's a plural-only noun because it denotes an object made up of two like parts. The bipartite nature of "binoculars" comes from it containing two pieces of glass.

Comment: And like many things in language, a lot of this is convention and not strict logic. Like -- and sorry if this seems like a vulgar example -- why do we say "a pair of underpants". I don't see any "pair" there. But we don't say, "a pair of bras" even though it has two cups. (Well, if you said "a pair of bras" people would understand you to mean two separate garments with a total of four cups.) Maybe there's some etymological explanation, but in practice it really comes down to, you just have to learn the convention for each word or phrase.

Answer (score 1):

You may think of "binoculars" as being very similar to "scissors", which only appear in plural due to having two parts to the whole.  They are referred to as a pair, (e.g. "a pair of binoculars" or "a pair of scissors").  So despite the "bi-" prefix, it is a **binary plural** and therefore always appears plural.

Per: https://www.optics-trade.eu/blog/why-is-the-word-binoculars-plural/ and
https://www.mentalfloss.com/article/52672/11-nouns-only-have-plural-form

Answer (score 0):

I think you will just have to learn the usage: *binoculars*, *pants*, and *scissors* are all treated as plural (as Astralbee says, they are all short for "a *pair of* [x]") and *bicycle* is treated as singular.

I don't think there is a cohesive "rule" that explains why this is so; it simply is.

Comment: Maybe not a good rule, but certainly a good explanation - all of these items consist of two halves: pants were originally two separate pieces loosely tied together; binoculars are essentially two telescopes tied together; scissors are two knives rivetted together.